# Создание временного объекта при приравнивание в конструкторе

Tags: c++

Если есть такой код:

```
class A {
private:
    B mB;
public:
    A(B b) {
        mb = b;
    }
}
```

Согласно, данному [источнику](https://www.interviewsansar.com/2014/09/28/initialization-lists-vs-assignment-in-class-constructor-performance/):

> Whereas using assignment is the two-step process i.e. define the
>   object and then assign it. Defining objects calls default constructor
>   and then assignment calls assignment operator. Hence, expensive
>   operations.

Т.е. где-то происходит вызов конструктора, но где?

Comment: Конструктор объекта `mb` будет вызван в списке инициализации

Comment: @bobtorus будет вызван конструктор копирования. Это очевидно. Но в статье по ссылке говорится о вызове `default constructor` для assignment'а

Comment: При попадании в тело конструктора `A` подъобъект `mB` уже будет инициализирован конструктором по-умолчанию (посредством кода, сгенерированного компилятором). Никакого конструктора копирования в этом примере не вызвается.

Comment: @VTT конструктор копирования будет вызван при наличии списка инициализации. Разве нет?

Comment: В этом примере список инициализации отсутствует.

Comment: Да но bob torus про него говорил. Я думал ваш коммент относится к моему ответу на комментарий bob torus

Comment: @wcobalt, даже если списка инициализации нет, все подобъекты должы быть сконструированы до попадания в тело конструктора.

Comment: Мои комментарии относятся только к коду, приведенному в вопросе. Кстати временных объектов в нем тоже нет. Хотя странно, что аргумент передается по значению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class B {
public:
    B() :
    p{0}
    {
        std::cout << "B default ctr\n";
    }

    B(const B& b):
    p{b.p}
    {
        std::cout << "B copy ctr\n";
    }

    B& operator =(const B& b) {
        std::cout << "B = opr\n";
        this->p = b.p;
        return *this;
    }
    ~B() {}
    int p;
};

class A {
private:
    B mB;     //(3)
public:
    A(B b) {
        mB = b;  //(4)
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B b;     //(1)
    A a(b);  //(2)
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получим:

```
B default ctr       (1)
B copy ctr          (2) - вызывается, т.к. объект B передаётся в конструктор A 
                          не по константной ссылке
B default ctr       (3) - вызывается при объявлении в классе A перед вызовом 
                          тела конструктора А
B = opr             (4)
```

Comment: Т.е. никаких временных объектов не создаётся. О чем же тогда говорилось в статье?

Comment: @wcobalt " i.e. define the object(3) and then assign it (4)."

Comment: @wcobalt В статье говорится о том, что в таком примере происходит инициализация + присваивание, тогда как можно обойтись только инициализацией.

Comment: @VTT вы имеете ввиду что при приравнивание, сначала мемберы инициализируется через их конструкторы по умолчанию а потом вызывается оператор=? А разве при списке инициализации конструкторы по умолчанию вызваны не будут?

Comment: @wcobalt Если бы вместо присваивания тут был список инициализации, то был бы вызван только конструктор, использованный в списке инициализации. Инициализация не может быть произведена дважды

Comment: @VTT вот что я не понял. Спасибо